What kind of epistemology would justify accepting religious claims that lie beyond the reach of scientific and historical verification?
Preamble:

The question Can all truths be scientifically verified? explores the possibility of truths that cannot be scientifically verified.
The question Can science or history be used to examine religions claims despite it being a naturalist enterprise that denies the existence of the supernatural? examines the limits of applying science and history to investigate religious claims.

Based on these, I think it is at least epistemically conceivable that some religious claims might be true, even though they cannot be conclusively established using the epistemological tools of science or history.
Now, consider an arbitrary religious worldview RW. We can divide the set of all claims made by RW into three subsets:

RWS: claims in RW that can reasonably be established through the scientific method.
RWH: claims in RW that can reasonably be established through historical methods.
RWnot-H/S: claims in RW that cannot be reasonably established through scientific or historical methods.

Given this, the subsets RWS and RWH are likely less interesting, as they probably consist of well-established facts in both science and history. A well-informed scientist, when presented with a claim from RWS, might respond, "Yes, we already knew that." Similarly, a well-informed historian might react to a claim from RWH by saying, "Yes, we historians already knew that."
The subset RWnot-H/S, however, is more intriguing and likely more controversial. If science cannot be used to establish claims in RWnot-H/S, and if history is likewise ineffective, what other epistemological tools might allow us to evaluate the truth of such claims, especially with a level of confidence comparable to that which science or history can provide?
NOTE: I aim to be charitable to religious worldviews. While I recognize that staunch atheists might argue there are no viable epistemological alternatives to science or history, I am interested in hearing charitable perspectives that entertain plausible alternatives. These alternatives might offer promising ways to explore the truth of claims in RWnot-H/S.

Examples of religious claims defying scientific and historical verification

The Existence of God (Monotheistic Religions)
The Resurrection of Jesus (Christianity)
The Existence of Heaven or Hell (Christianity, Islam)
Reincarnation (Hinduism, Buddhism)
The Nirvana Experience (Buddhism)
The Intercession of Saints or Deities (Christianity, Hinduism)
The Presence of Karma (Hinduism, Buddhism, Jainism)
Sacred Texts as Direct Revelations (Various Religions)
The Existence of Ghosts and Spirits (Various Traditions)
Paranormal Activity (Various Beliefs)
Communication with the Dead (Spiritualism, Mediumship)
Astral Projection (New Age, Occult)
Psychic Abilities (Clairvoyance, Telepathy, etc.)
Astrology and Its Influence on Personality and Life Events (Various Cultures)
The Law of Attraction (New Age Belief)

NOTE 2: I’m not aware of any compelling scientific or historical cases that conclusively support these claims. For example, while Christian apologetics has extensively defended the historicity of the resurrection account, these arguments are met with strong counterarguments from scholars with more skeptical perspectives, making it a highly debated and contentious topic. At best, these claims are open to debate but remain far from achieving the status of scientific or historical knowledge. So in order to accept them, I think it's unlikely that science or history could convincingly get us there. Other epistemological tools would be necessary for that.

@KristianBerry Even things that purportedly happened in the past are not necessarily historically decidable. The most obvious example that comes to mind is the purported resurrection of Jesus, which to the best of my understanding is historically undecidable, although apologists might argue otherwise.

"Reformed epistemology is a thesis about the rationality of religious belief. A central claim made by the reformed epistemologist is that religious belief can be rational without any appeal to evidence or argument... Plantinga, when wondering how theistic belief might be grounded, suggests that we consider that Calvin may have been right when he said that God has created humans with an inner awareness of himself and it is this sensus divinitatis that is responsible for theistic belief." IEP, Reformed Epistemology.

See the interesting IEP's entry linked by @Conifold: if we have a Number sense: an intuition about numbers, we may also assume the hypothesis of a "sensus divinitatis that is responsible for theistic belief. " Is this helpful? Maybe... Is this "philosophy of science"? Obviously not.

All devout RWs can turn into cats and surf around on rainbows - but only when nobody except for devout RWs is watching, and only if they clean up afterwards so well that no non-RWs can ever find out, and never tell anybody other than RWs about it. (RWGod can tell ahead of time if you're going to clean up and if non-RWs would find out, it's sort of his thing.)

@Conifold How is the idea of an innate sensus divinitatis reconciled with the fact that many nonbelievers do not consciously "sense the divine"? The problem of divine hiddenness comes to mind in this context.

Calvin and Plantinga do not cite divine hiddenness, they cite the fall and the sin, see Helm:"The fall is a moral rupture between the Creator and mankind with (among other things) noetic consequences. These consequences are not such that, being fallen, a person is unable to count, or to reason... A person does not now see his self-interest bound up with the knowledge and service of God. And as a result of this, he misinterprets relevant evidence, he suppresses evidence, he accepts common opinion, and so on." Wrong apple trees cast a long shadow.

Why are some people so unhappy to accept that science and history are not all-knowing and all-powerful and so there are areas they can't reach to validate claims? Who exactly is being kept awake at night by that? It doesn't bother me at all. This idea seems to mainly be pondered by theists.

@IdiosyncraticSoul I appended a few examples to my question. Please let me know if this meets your requirements.

@user80226 I've retacted my vote to close

I consider at least two extra areas, witness accounts and qualia (see second half of answer).
The main churches rely on witness accounts of miracles that happened without leaving other objective traces of having happened.
There is no special "epistemology of testimony" about this, rather epistemology points out all the problems with this to make this a very unreliable transmission of "truths" that works just as well (and sometimes even better) for lies.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/testimony-episprob/

So much of what we know about the world, e.g., history, science, politics, one another, etc., comes from the testimony of others. But while testimony is clearly an indispensable source of knowledge, specifying exactly how it is that we are able to learn from a speaker’s say-so has proven to be a difficult task.

Still, it is also undeniable some truths can only be witnessed once and would be lost unless reported to others. But since they cannot be distinguished from lies and delusions, they have only limited value as "truths" and would typically be treated instead as beliefs lacking proof in epistemology.
Also see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_testimony

The role of testimony in acquiring belief and knowledge has been a relatively neglected philosophical issue. CAJ (Tony) Coady[3] believes that this is because traditional epistemology has had a distinctly individualist flavour.

I found this book online which seems to pursue that idea, though I cannot speak for it's quality having only read it's summary: "Epistemic Authority: A Theory of Trust, Authority, and Autonomy in Belief by
Linda Trinkaus Zagzebski"

A separate possible source or truths outside what history and science can cover are qualia. Religious worldviews can make claims that certain practices (like prayers, or drinking the blood of virgins) will reward the individual with special inner experiences. Qualia being difficult to analyze scientifically from the outside, there is a loophole for subjective truths. But psychologically such claims are fraught with risk of abuse, and the experiences cannot be distinguished from harmful delusions, so philosophy stays well away from that in general.
Dreams in particular have been seen as truth-revealing in popular culture and some esoteric theories (even some people in psychology literature consider their analysis useful).

I like this answer. The sensus divinitatis mentioned by Conifold in the context of Reformed Epistemology can be seen as a particular instance of qualia, that takes advantage of this "loophole for subjective truths".

"some truths can only be witnessed once and would be lost unless reported to others. But since they cannot be distinguished from lies and delusions, they are unacceptable to a skeptic." A skeptic is willing to miss out on truth because the means by which the truth is conveyed allows for the possibility of falsehood?

@Brendan If some seemingly regular person lies to you 50% of the time, would you believe them if they tell you earlier they flew around like superman, or would you doubt that and be "willing to miss out on truth because the means by which the truth is conveyed allows for the possibility of falsehood"? This isn't some absurd reasoning that only skeptics use, it's something everyone uses, for good reason. Skeptics just try to be more consistent about when and how they use it.

@NotThatGuy If 500 other people claimed to have seen that person flying around like Superman, I wouldn't discredit the claim on the sole basis that testimony can be unreliable.

@Brendan I presented an example of an unreliable means of coming to beliefs. Your response is to present a different example, which you'd think there may be some merit to because it's much more reliable - that's just supporting the point I made. Although if I find you 500 people who claim to have seen someone fly around like Superman, or other extraordinary events that you don't accept, I suspect you'd still doubt that, because you don't consider eyewitness testimony to be THAT reliable. Also note: I said you'd doubt it, not that you'd dismiss it based solely on testimony being unreliable.

@NotThatGuy It's the same example! I'm talking about your guy. My point is that the thing I quoted is misguided; the quote seems to say that no event that happened once is worthy of being considered as true, I think that's wrong, and the way we try to separate truth from lies is to, among other things, look at the quality of the reporting/transmission of the claim. An unreliable narrator making a wild claim is evaluated differently than 500 people supporting the unreliable narrator's claim.

@Brendan "It's the same example" - it's "the same" only if you ignore the specifics. You are faced with different facts in each case (how many people say it), so it's a different example. You're presenting a different example where you might be able to distinguish truth from lies and delusions (although I doubt you'd accept it as true even with 500 people), so that wouldn't actually be a response to "they cannot be distinguished from lies and delusions" (which is the text you quoted). Yeah, there exists ways to distinguish, sometimes. But we're talking about cases where those ways don't apply.

@Brendan a good question, if only there was a function on this site to ask questions...

@tkruse the purpose of asking was to make sure I understood your position correctly. I think if the question was phrased that way it would be closed swiftly.

@NotThatGuy "we're talking about cases" - we?

Skepticism is a philosophic school of thought, it's a good topic for this site, and it's dealing with testimony is interesting. For my answer, it's not an important point, I can weaken it if you like.

What kind of epistemology would justify *accepting* religious claims? A bad* one (in my opinion, at least).
We can and do use the exact same epistemology to evaluate religious claims that we use in every other part of life (including, but not limited to, science and history), and which is exceedingly effective in those other parts. The issue (for religious people) is that those don't lead to concluding that religious claims are true.

We use science to test the efficacy of prayer. But we fail to see an effect, we get mixed results, and in some cases we even see prayer having the opposite effect.

We use science to determine the history and age of Earth and life and the universe. This doesn't match the history and age given by some religious claims.

We evaluate personal religious experiences according to well-studied criteria for hallucination, and hallucination ends up being the better explanation.

We evaluate religious eyewitness testimony similar to how we evaluate eyewitness testimony more broadly. While we have historically put too much weight into it, it's one of the least reliable forms of evidence, so it fails to hold up the extraordinary religious claims people make. This is especially true when we dig into the difference between direct sensory experience and the interpretation or memory of said experience, and relevant context that makes it less reliable (see also: the hallucination link above).

We evaluate religious texts according to principles of historical analysis of favouring simpler explanations, and we compare those texts to other writings at the same time (and also to texts of other religions making contradictory claims). Based on that we conclude that their miraculous claims probably just didn't happen, and instead these are fictional, or partially fictional, stories.

We study the brain and the history of human development, and we find no "soul-shaped" hole where the "soul" claimed by various religions would fit in. On the contrary, we keep narrowing and eliminating gaps where a soul could potentially have formed and how it could exist and what it could be responsible for, by finding evidence for the evolution of an uninterrupted line (to oversimplify) of increasing complexity of the brain, as well as strong links between various parts of human consciousness and various parts of our physical brains, with directly measurable effects of thinking on activity in those parts of the brain, and damage to those parts of our brains very directly affecting our personality.
While the "soul" is an unverifiable and unfalsifiable claim, if it were true, it would be surprising for us to be able to explain so much of human consciousness through physical means. I'd have expected that to remain much more of a black box, with our sensory input seemingly just disappearing into places outside of measurement, and some physical response popping up out of nowhere, but that's not what we see.

We use Occam's razor and the criteria of explanatory power (both extensively used in science and history and a big part of abductive reasoning) to reject religious claims with little to no explanatory or predictive power, or which can be better explained through natural means (e.g. I felt a thing because of normal human emotions instead of it being because of some divine entity inside me, poking at my brain, or however that's supposed to work).

There are also logical arguments (e.g. arguments from design, complexity, the cosmological argument, etc). Theists will say these are sound arguments, while skeptics point to what seem like fallacies, and say these typically don't get you all that close to any specific deity that you can say much anything about or that would make any difference in how we should live our lives, and that these arguments are so abstract and far-removed from reality that you could probably use those to end up with any conclusion if you pick your premises well enough. Then there are also things like the problem of evil, divine hiddenness, hell, etc., that challenges specific god claims.



* If you're asking how we can evaluate religious claims, see above. If you specifically want a means of evaluation that would lead you to conclude that religious claims are true, it doesn't seem to be the case that they are (or at least we don't have justified reason to think any that have been presented are true, as per my evaluation). So if that's the case, you'd be asking for a "bad" epistemology by definition - you'd be asking for an epistemology that tells you something is true when in fact it's false or unjustified.

So I would partly agree that there are religious epistemological considerations that go beyond scientific and historical verification.  Here are a few that the Bible would include as valid epistemology:

Internal witness.  Since this is so subjective, it's not easily debated.  But for example, the Bible talks about God's revealing certain things individually, within the heart, which the Bible would say serves as a valid epistemological basis (e.g., Matthew 16:17).
Internal confirmation.  Very closely related to #1, but this is a "confirmation" in the heart regarding, e.g., historic and scientific claims.  For example, in Romans 1, in verse 19, Paul talks about how God has "showed" things to people (implying individual testimony in the heart), but then in the next verse he talks about scientific evidence.  And so this kind of confirmation is not necessarily something brand new, and not so much a separate epistemology, but a "clarity of mind" brought about by God regarding existing epistemology.  I'd say it's partly like God clearing away "epistemological fog" regarding scientific and historical claims.
Revelation of personal motives.  For example, if the Bible reveals things about a person's individual heart, where nothing else adequately does so in the same way, the Bible considers this a valid epistemological basis (I Corinthians 14:25).
Spiritual explanatory power.  I.e., explanatory power regarding human nature (leaving scientific and historic considerations aside for now).  This is broadly what the Bible calls "light"--whatever reveals, explains, or makes obvious (Ephesians 5:13), and biblically, it's considered a good part of epistemology.  Examples might include explaining our strong innate sense of objective moral right and wrong; our sense of desiring ultimate justice, even when all involved have already died without justice; a strong sense in humans regarding an afterlife; a strong tendency for cultures generally to believe in God (or some kind of gods); a strong sense that our lives ought to have enduring meaning to them; etc.  While some competing hypotheses (like evolution) do attempt to explain all of these things, in my view, these explanations are not satisfactory, especially given the weight of these aspects of human nature.

But I also think it's important to add another key point here: A difference in epistemological threshold is sometimes mistaken for a difference in epistemological category.  Put another way, oftentimes, the difference is not with the kind of evidence, but in the threshold of accepting that evidence as "convincing" toward certain conclusions (e.g., when the claims are particularly impactful).
For example, suppose that you inspect a roller coaster for safety.  All the evidence indicates that it is reliable, and running the coaster through during several test runs confirms this.  Let's say you are personally terrified of riding these contraptions!  You need more assurrance than a "very probably safe" to jump in and fasten your harness.  Fair enough; but you are faced with a critical danger right about now (epistemologically speaking, that is).  You are tempted to conflate your personal reservations with evidential probability.  You are tempted to say that, in the matter of this coaster's safety, the evidence is "unconvincing" and "ambiguous."  Being thrown upside down and going through negative g-forces is an extraordinary thing, and it requires extraordinary evidence to believe that this sort of thing is very probably safe.  Yet this is conflating two distinct concepts: (1) The probabilistic nature of the evidence; versus, (2) A personal threshold for trusting one's life to this particular conclusion.  "Belief" in common usage can refer to either, while "trust" refers specifically to the second.
The personal import of a claim should not contaminate an accurate perception of the probabilistic nature of the evidence.  If a person is unwilling to trust a claim because of personal import, that is a distinct matter from probability.  The accurate thing would be to say, "This roller coaster is indeed very probably safe given this evidence; but I personally need a lot more than that before you'll ever catch me riding one."
I believe this same basic principle affects some of the examples you bring up.  For instance, there are lots of trivial facts of history which people generally believe on far less historical evidence than the resurrection of Jesus Christ; but I would say the difference is that the others have little to no personal import.  Many people believe that the multiverse is probably true even though it is not directly observable at all.  Yet evidence of design in nature, which is so strikingly analogous to manmade objects requiring highly intelligent manufacturing processes, is considered ambiguous or unconvincing as evidence of a Creator.  I would argue that what is called a different kind of epistemology is actually, in many cases, a simple difference in the threshold of trust for particular propositions, often due to their unique import.  I'd say it's important to keep these two concepts distinct.

OK, so you appear to be saying that claims like "God exists" can be established scientifically, and claims like the resurrection of Jesus can be established historically. And yet this is not the consensus among scientists and historians. And you are probably aware that both claims are highly contested and debates abound. But leaving that aside, in your answer you admit at the beginning: I would partly agree that there are religious epistemological considerations that go beyond scientific and historical verification". Can you please elaborate more on these epistemological considerations?

The main focus of my question is on epistemological tools that go beyond science and history, but it looks like you devoted your entire answer to attempting to justify the scientific/historical status of specific religious claims, while forgetting to address the main point being asked about, which is epistemological alternatives for religious claims that do not fall within the purview of science and history.

@user80226 Fair enough, good idea.  I've added a few non-scientific/historic epistemological considerations that the Bible gives.  At first, I was just trying to point out that a lack of scientific/historic consensus sometimes has far less to do with the probabilistic nature of the evidence, and far more to do with the import of a claim.  And while the debate has transcended science and history in such cases, the epistemology of those accepting the claim can actually be quite scientific/historic in the normal sense; those rejecting are bringing in extra-science/historical considerations.

If the most compelling evidence is internal to each person, it will be difficult to build any kind of consensus on that. Or at least, to trust that it is objectively valid. Beliefs don't seem to be the kind of things we can hang our hats on.

I think it also seems that if the deciding factor amounts to a purely internal evaluation based on internal evidence, then everyone has an absolute right to their assessment, and no one should be trying to convince anyone or draw any conclusions based on someone's beliefs. In other words: the modern secular approach to religious belief has to govern public behavior about it. Good conclusion.

The resurrection is not disbelieved because of import but because it is an extraordinary claim - our experience of the world is not such that resurrection is possible. It falls not with historical trivia but with other magical claims.

@JackAidley But could it be that the a priori commitment to naturalism is actually due to import?  True, a resurrection is a highly unusual and supernatural event, but the individual pieces of evidence can be entirely natural (e.g., that Jesus died, and that He was seen alive afterwards).  Ripples in water can indicate that something transcending the pond recently perturbed it; and likewise, I'd say that natural science can bear the marks of the past work of the supernatural as well.  I think it would be begging the question against the supernatural to dismiss that possibility.

Religion is, when we understand the term corectly, supernatural. That is, it is over and above nature and grounds nature. Conventionally, the supernatural means ghosts and tgeir ilk. This is not the notion we mean by supernatural here.
Any epistemology that doubts the existence of the supernatural, such as modern scientific or historical epistemology, will not be able to fit the supernatural in its schema of things.
However, there are epistemologies which allow for an element of the supernatural. For example, Aristotle, in his Metaphysics explained the origin of the world by following the causal chain through to a First Mover. However, he would have regarded the First Mover as natural. This has been identified in some Christian & Islamic philosophies as God.


Your search for such an epistemology has a long past in the history
of philosophy. Greek philosophers from the classical time
discriminated between  knowledge (episteme) and opinion (doxa). The
discussion emphasized that knowledge is more, because it adds
argumentation and justification to pure opinion.

IMO it must be possible that every partner of the discussion can
check the arguments presented in the discussion. This excludes
argumentation on a purely subjective basis.
One should also check that the claim is stated in a way which does not immunize the claim against any refutation.
Nevertheless, there remain claims which are not decidable, either
principally or - at least - not with our present knowledge.



There remain a lot of claims which are not decidable with our present knowledge, fortunately.
